# Strange behavior of NIntegrate: small change of integration range give tremendous running time difference!

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I have an integrand:

```
integrand =   
 E^((6*I)*x - x^2 - (6*I)*y - y^2)/(2 Pi (-I (I/100 + x - y))^(1/3))
```

This function decays as $\sim e^{-x^2-y^2}$ for $x,y \to \pm\infty$, and has a smeared-out power-law singularity $\sim (x-y+i/100)^{-1/3}$ at $x=y$. This function is absolutely integrable. I want to integrate this function over $(x,y) \in [-r,r]^2$, by changing $r\in \mathbb R$.

Since the integrand decays exponentially, as long as $r$ is not too small, the result should be nearly independent of $r$. However, consider the following code, where I varied $r=4,5,20,\infty$:

```
r = 4;
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.94145, 7.426*10^-9} *)

r = 5;
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {313.612, 4.16386*10^-9} *)

r = 20;
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0731268, 0. + 0. I} *)

r = Infinity;
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.09029, 2.01522*10^-9 - 3.09162*10^-16 I} *)
```

There are two strange behaviors:

1. For $r=5$, the computation time is abnormally large.
2. I think the reasonable value of the integral is of $10^{-9}$. However, for $r=20$, the computation time is abnormally fast and the result is 0. I think this result is wrong.

Why this strange thing happen, and how can one fix it?

Comment: You should adapt WorkingPrecision for different values of r!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of the integrals under consideration are close to zero and this causes problems. Here is a possible workaround which consists in adding `1/(1+x^2)/(1+y^2)` to `integrand` and then subtracting its contribution.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; integrand = E^((6*I)*x - x^2 - (6*I)*y - 
y^2)/(2 Pi (-I (I/100 + x - y))^(1/3)); r = 5;
NIntegrate[integrand + 1/(1 + x^2)/(1 + y^2), {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
AccuracyGoal -> 12] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{13.1495, 7.54492}`

```
NumberForm[Last[%],16]
```

> `7.544918670742604`

```
%-N[4*ArcTan[r]^2,18]
```

> `4.16197*10^-9`

For `r=20` we have `4.162*10^-9`.